# Blazor return 404 as header

Tags: c#, http, iis, blazor

So I've tried to play with Blazor (not a WebAssembly) for a bit and stuck with Redirects and Headers response.

Post.cs:

```
    public class PostService
    {
        public List<Post> posts = new List<Post>()
        {
            new Post { ID = 1, Title = "First title", Text = "first text", Date = DateTime.Now, Author = "JohnDoe", Category = "Good" },
            new Post { ID = 2, Title = "Second title", Text = "second text", Date = DateTime.Now, Author = "JohnDoe", Category = "Nice" }
        };
        public Task<List<Post>> GetPosts()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(posts);
        }
        public Task<Post> GetPost(int id)
        {
            Post post = posts.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return Task.FromResult(post);
        }
    }
```

BlogPost.razor:

```
@page "/post/{ID:int}"
@using ExampleBlog.Data;
@inject PostService PostClassService
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager

@if (post == null)
{
    <p>Loading</p>
}
else
{
    @post.Text
}
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Post post { get; set; }
    public bool found { get; set; } = true;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        post = await PostClassService.GetPost(ID);
        if (post == null)
        {
            found = false;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            if (!found)
            {
                _navigationManager.NavigateTo("404");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works great, it shows post.Text if ID is correct and redirects to 404 **in browser** correctly.

Problem is server headers returning:

```
curl -i --insecure https://localhost:44332/post/1
HTTP/2 200
```

Its ok, works fine, but if I will try to reach non existent entity:

```
curl -i --insecure https://localhost:44332/post/1234
HTTP/2 200
```

I need to return 404 **server-side** so Search Engines, etc will recognise everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It not returning not found because it actually is finding the pages route signature `Post(int)`.
Try putting a break point in there.

You need something like

```
public Task<Post> GetPost(int id)
 {
     Post post = posts.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
     if (post == null)
     { 
         return NotFound();
     }
     else
     {
         return Task.FromResult(post);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found **bad** workaround which works fine.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    post = await PostClassService.GetPost(ID);
    if (post == null)
    {
        found = false;

        #if !DEBUG
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo("404");
        #endif
}
```

#debug is needed because of blazor bug which throwing exception with NavigationManager while you are in Debug.

and changed EndPoints in Startup.cs

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            endpoints.MapGet("/404", async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("404 not found");
            });
        });
```

If I running it in release, everything works fine (except it's returns blank page with 404 not found)

```
curl -i --insecure https://localhost:44332/post/1 
HTTP/2 200

curl -i --insecure https://localhost:44332/post/1234
HTTP/2 302
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
location: https://localhost:44332/404
```